# How to convert nullable int to SQL Null value?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I need to perform an update to a View that has multiple underlying tables using the ExecuteCommand method of a DataContext. I am using this method because of the known restriction of linqToSQL when performing this type of operation on Views having multiple underlying tables.

My existing SQL statement is similar to the following where I am setting newFieldID to a null value simply for this post to illustrate the issue. In the application, newFieldID is assigned a passed parameter and could actually be an integer value; but my question is specific to the case where the value being provided is a null type:

```
using (var _ctx = new MyDataContext())
{
   int? newFieldID = null;
   var updateCmd = "UPDATE [SomeTable] SET fieldID = " + newFieldID + " 
   WHERE keyID = " + someKeyID;

   try
   {
      _ctx.ExecuteCommand(updateCmd);
      _ctx.SubmitChanges();
   }
   catch (Exception exc)
   {
      // Handle the error...
   }
}
```

This code will fail for the obvious reason that the updateCmd won't be completed in the case of a null value for the newFieldID. So how can I replace or translate the CLR null value with an SQL null to complete the statement?

I know I could move all of this to a Stored Procedure but I am looking for an answer to the existing scenario. I've tried experimenting with DBNull.Value but aside from the challenge of substituting it for the newFieldID to use in the statement, simply placing it into the string breaks the validity of the statement.

Also, enclosing it within a single quotes:

```
var updateCmd = "UPDATE [SomeTable] SET fieldID = '" + DBNull.Value + "'
   WHERE keyID = " + someKeyID;
```

Will complete the statement but the value of the field is translated to an integer 0 instead of an SQL null.

So How does one go about converting a CLR null or nullable int to an SQL Null value given this situation?

Comment: Please *don't* use string concatenation. Create a parameterized query and pass your parameter *as is*. The problem isn't how to convert the nullable integer.

Comment: First, you should use parameterized queries. Here you could simply write "fieldID = null" when newFieldID is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking newFieldID == null and change the statement accordingly.
Something like below or using separate if / else statement.

```
var updateCmd = "UPDATE [SomeTable] SET fieldID =" + (newFieldID == null ? "null" : Convert.ToString(newFieldID)) + " WHERE keyID = " + someKeyID;
```

Answer (score 4):

Correct way to do it: use [override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `ExecuteCommand` accepting not only command text, but also array of parameters and use parameterized query instead of command string concatenation:

```
var updateCmd = "UPDATE [SomeTable] SET fieldID = {0} WHERE keyID = {1}";
_ctx.ExecuteCommand(updateCmd, new [] {newFieldID, someKeyID});
```

It will not only prevent you from sql injection, but also it will do following for you (from MSDN description):

> If any one of the parameters is null, it is converted to DBNull.Value.

Comment: I like this solution but how would you implement it if the parameter values varied? In other words, the case here is with an integer but suppose the parameter list inferred an implicitly typed array which could include integer, string and boolean values?

Comment: @Mark Since type of second method parameter is `object[]` - just use explicitly typed array of objects in that case: `new object[] {integerParam, stringParam, booleanParam}`.

Comment: attempting to use the object array errors in "A query parameter cannot be of type 'System.Object'". Any idea as to why? This is .NET 4.5. Nonetheless, I am going to accept your answer, I like it.

Comment: @Mark oops.... while searching for possible reason of behaviour you've described, I've switched framework version in MSDN article I've mentioned from current one to [version 4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Comments below that version of article proves that this method is actually broken and Microsoft doesn't attempts to fix it. So  it looks like my answer was totally useless to you, sorry....

Comment: on the contrary your initial answer addressed the context of the initial question so you were dead on point. My question of passing different parameter types was somewhat a branch off the initial question. Thanks!

Comment: Komeyev, my mistake as it appears you were correct in stating the initially proposed solution would not work for this situation. I thought you were speaking in reference to the passing of array type object which is apparently not supported but after testing I realize I cannot pass null values in a parameterized list. "A query parameter cannot be of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32][]'. I am going to post my workaround  solution as a potential answer but I still believe your contribution to the question was valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when using Stored Procedures or Prepared Statements, you use Parameters to assign values. When you have a `DbParameter`, you can assign `null` or `DBNull.Value` to the Value-Property or your parameter.

If you want to have the `null` as text in the statement, simply use the SQL-keyword `NULL`

```
var updateCmd = "UPDATE [SomeTable] SET fieldID = NULL WHERE keyID = " + someKeyID;
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Andy Korneyev and others, a parameterized array approach is the best and probably the more appropriate method when using Prepared statements. Since I am using LinqToSQL, the ExecuteCommand method with the second argument which takes an array of parameters would be advised but it has the following caveats to its usage.

1. A query parameter cannot be of type System.Nullable`1[System.Int32][] (The main issue I'm trying to resolve in this case)
2. All parameters must be of the same type

Shankar's answer works although it can quickly become very verbose as the number of parameters could potentially increase.

So my workaround for the problem involve somewhat of a hybrid between the use of parameters as recommended by Andy and Shankar's suggestion by creating a helper method to handle the null values which would take an SQL statement with parameter mappings and the actual parameters.

My helper method is:

```
private static string PrepareExecuteCommand (string sqlParameterizedCommand, object [] parameterArray) 
    {
        int arrayIndex = 0;
        foreach (var obj in parameterArray)
        {
            if (obj == null || Convert.IsDBNull(obj)) 
            {
                sqlParameterizedCommand = sqlParameterizedCommand.Replace("{" + arrayIndex + "}", "NULL"); 
            }
            else
                sqlParameterizedCommand = sqlParameterizedCommand.Replace("{" + arrayIndex + "}", obj.ToString());
            ++arrayIndex;
        }
        return sqlParameterizedCommand;
    }
```

So I can now execute my statement with parameters having potential null values like this:

```
int? newFieldID = null;
int someKeyID = 12;
var paramCmd = "UPDATE [SomeTable] SET fieldID = {0} WHERE keyID = {1}";
var newCmd = PrepareExecuteCommand(paramCmd, new object[] { newFieldID });

_ctx.ExecuteCommand(newCmd);
_ctx.SubmitChanges();
```

This alleviates the two previously referenced limitations of the ExecuteCommand with a parameter array. Null values get translated appropriately and the object array may varied .NET types.

I am marking Shankar's proposal as the answer since it sparked this idea but posting my solution because I think it adds a bit more flexibility.